# Why doesn't ISO27001 mandate an acceptable use policy?

Tags: iso27001

I'm going through my first ISO27001 implementation and I can't seem to find a definitive list of what policies are required. I realise Annex A is "optional".

I've found lists online a few times on a few different sites. I've dumped it into a table and grabbed the descriptions and headings from the actual ISO27001/27002 documentation for the individual controls highlighting any literal policy reference I can find.

[image]

The only odd one out I can't find in the official documentation is A.8.1.3 Acceptable Use of Information Assets.

I've always been lead to believe an AUP is a mandatory document and a lot of sites online seem to agree with this.

Is it not under ISO or am I missing something? I've not had formal ISO training but I do have my CISSP so I understand the controls, but I'm only starting to get my head round 27001.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking. You say that AUP is not mandatory, but it's on the list? I think you are missing some context for what that list is and how it relates to your question.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between "rules" and "policies"?

Comment: Apologies yes I'm missing some context, sorry! The list I've grabbed from the above keeps coming up as "mandatory policies" online, so I've dumped it into a table and grabbed all the references I can find. The only one on the online list that I can't find a policy reference for is the AUP. Sorry!

Comment: Do you have access to the actual ISO 27001 document? Or are you only working from secondary lists? And it looks like AUP is on the list, as you highloghted. I'm confused about what you are asking or what your confusion is.

Comment: Updated the OP. And yeah I'm working from ISO27001 and 2

Comment: This is what I'm reading in your post: "AUP does not appear in lists. All I can find is AUP in this list". Can you explain your confusion differently?

Comment: I've updated the OP with a bit more detail. tldr AUP keeps coming up online as a mandatory policy, the official documentation doesn't mention an AUP. Why?

Comment: Ok, I keep asking the same question over and over. You say that an AUP isn't mentioned, but there it is in the list you posted and in A.8.1.3. Explain like I'm 5: what are you *expecting* to see and how is what you are seeing *not that*?

Comment: @schroeder No it's not stating "policy" anywhere. I've been really specific with what I've pasted into that table. If you look in the table, there is an explicit mention of "policy" in each one EXCEPT A.8.1.3. it doesn't mention the word policy anywhere in either the heading or the description. I'm sorry you feel like you've gone round and round but the table hasn't changed since the first I posted it!

Comment: So, my 2nd comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue can be summed up with a misunderstanding of the term "policy". Many people use the term "policy" to mean many things:

- strategy
- guidance
- direction
- procedures
- mandates
- technical specifications

But these are all different types of documents. [ISO 27000 defines](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:27000:ed-5:v1:en) "policy" specifically:

> **policy** 
> intentions and direction of an organization (3.50), as formally expressed by its top management (3.75)

For A.8.1.3, they are not looking for a "policy" (i.e. intentions and directions). They are looking for "rules" (i.e. "do this").

So, while people generally call the document an "Acceptable Use *Policy*" (AUP), it's not a policy as defined by ISO 27000. It's a set of rules users are meant to follow without deviation.

And, as you can see in the list you posted, it's there.

Comment: I'd also refer to ISO 27002 sections 5.1.1 and 8.1.3, which explicitly call for defined, approved, published, and communicated policies (5.1.1) and rules being defined for the acceptable use of information and assets being identified, documented, and implemented (8.1.3).

Comment: All that detail is provided by the OP. That's already known ...

Comment: That does clear that up yes. Historically I've taken policy as a much narrower definition. To me a policy is not a strategy, guidance, direction, procedures, mandates, technical, 
specifications. It might include those sure, almost all of them but it's not individually them. The ISO definition seems different from how I've been working with it for the last few years. Thank you @schroeder